# Don't show any fragment on a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm developing an Android application that uses `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`.

This `ViewPager` is on a `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` and it is going to show three fragments.

When I show the `FragmentActivity` it shows `Fragment` at index 0.

I want to do the following:

Don't show any fragment until users tap on a button.

**Is there any way to don't show a fragment on a `ViewPager`?**

If you need more details, please tell me and I add them.

Comment: What's stopping you from hiding the `ViewPager` or keeping the adapter empty until you need it with content?

Comment: Another downvote and nobody says why. Very instructive!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your first fragment invisible when setting in view pager and make it visible only when user presses button.

Answer (score 0):

Submit the `dataset` to the `PagerAdpater` only when the user press the button